# Why does not it get rid of duplicates when merging columns values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe values like this:

```
name             foreign_name   acronym  alias
United States   États-Unis       USA     USA
```

I want to merge all those four columns in a row into one single columns 'names', so I do:

```
merge = lambda x: '|'.join([a for a in x.unique() if a])
df['names'] = df[['name', 'foreign_name', 'acronym', 'alias',]].apply(merge, axis=1)
```

The problem with this code is that, it doesn't remove the duplicate 'USA', instead it gets:

```
names = 'United States|États-Unis|USA|USA'
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but you name your lamba above as 'merge' but then you call 'my_join'.  Otherwise if you change 'my_join' to 'merge' I works as expected 'United States|États-Unis|USA'.

Comment: @ScottBoston I corrected it!

Comment: It worked as expected for me.

Comment: @ScottBoston Do you test with a working example?

Comment: See answer below.... a fully working example.

Comment: Suggest you don't shadow the name `merge` because it's also a [pandas function name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). I'd call it `my_merge` or `str_merge` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d= {'name': {0: 'United States'},
 'foreign_name': {0: 'États-Unis'},
 'acronym': {0: 'USA'},
 'alias': {0: 'USA'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

merge = lambda x: '|'.join([a for a in x.unique() if a])
df['names'] = df[['name', 'foreign_name', 'acronym', 'alias',]].apply(merge, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            name foreign_name acronym alias                         names
0  United States   États-Unis     USA   USA  United States|États-Unis|USA
```

Answer (score 1):

aggregate to set to eliminate duplicates

Turn the set to list

apply `str.join('|')` to concat the strings with a `|` separator

```
df['name']=df.agg(set,1).map(list).str.join('|')
```

Comment: how do you specify the specific columns? There may be other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Give us a sample with the other columns. There are different ways to specificy columns and the one you apply will depend on the number of other columns and probably their location in the table. You could use the loc/iloc accessor  to slice and apply the aggregator. You could also use df.filter to filter and apply agg. Could also use a lambda expression. Give the sample dataset

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell is to operate along row axis. `axis=1`

```
df.apply(lambda r: "|".join(r.unique()), axis=1)
```

#### output

```
United    States|États-Unis|USA
dtype: object
```

Comment: What's 'r' in my example?

Comment: it's a naming convention I use... `r` is a series because I called with context `axis=1` I called it `r` to denote a row rather than `s` to denote a column